# Accessing Complex Javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object, something like this :

```
var obj = { simpleName: "some name"  name: { firstName: "anudeep", lastName : "rentala" }, address: { country: "XZ", state:"DF" } }
```

I also have another object like this :

```
var foo = { loc = "name.firstName" }
```

Depending on the `foo.loc` value, I'd have to access the value in `obj` object.
In this scenario, I'd need to access `obj.name.firstname`.
So, far, I've tried something like this:

```
  var props = foo.loc.split(".");
    for(var prop in props)
    {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        {
            alert(obj[prop])
        }
    }
```

My problem is, I can now access only the `name` property of `obj` object, how do I step into it, like `name.firstName`, I'm aware that `obj[name][firstName]` would work, but how do i do this dynamically ? Like extend this to `obj["prop1"]["prop2"]["prop3"] . .. .["propn"]`

Comment: 'foo'  array's  length determine how deep you must go in var 'obj'. A for loop will do the job.

Comment: Maybe just advance your obj pointer to the next value, like obj=obj[prop]

Comment: Hey @Andreas , that question also answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few missing `,`, and `firstname` vs `firstName`, but if you fix those, then this works great:

```
var obj = { simpleName: "some name",  name: { firstName: "anudeep", lastName : "rentala" }, address: { country: "XZ", state:"DF" } }
var foo = { loc: "name.firstName" }
var props = foo.loc.split(".");
var output = props.reduce( function(prev,prop) {
  if (prev.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
    return prev[prop]
  } else {
   // however you want to handle the error ...
  }
}, obj);
alert(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this to be way more elegant than the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your code like this:

```
var props = foo.loc.split(".");
var current = obj;
for(var prop in props)
{
  if (current.hasOwnProperty(prop))
  {
     current = current[prop];
     alert(current )
  }
}
```

but that probably won't be very useful once you start having more complex "selectors", for example, using arrays (`"names[2].firstname"`).

Comment: Thanks, foo.loc.split("."); was edited way back . But that's not really the problem anyway. extend it to obj["prop1"]["prop2"]["prop3"] . .. .["propn"] is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function:

```
var obj = { simpleName: "some name",  name: { firstName: "anudeep", lastName : "rentala" }, address: { country: "XZ", state:"DF" } };
var foo = { loc: "name.firstName" };

var checkObj = function(obj, props) {

    var temp = obj;

    for(var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(temp.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
            temp = temp[props[i]];
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return temp;
};

console.log(checkObj(obj, foo.loc.split('.')));
```